# Enable js file functions only if elements are in a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, phpbb3

I try to graphically integrate my phpbb forum (v3.1) in my bootstrap website. To do that I've added the bootstrap css file, my navabar in the `overall-header.html` and my footer in the `overall-footer.html`. To avoid conflicts, I've "encapsulated" the forum between `<div id="phpbb"></div>` so all phpbb's css has the prefix `#phpbb` (like in this [tutorial](http://www.jfusion.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=1816)).
My problem is when I've added the bootstrap css file, all the javascript of my forum has stopped working. 
So is it possible to enable forum js files functions only in the `<div id="phpbb"></div>` to avoid conflicts with bootstrap ? Indeed phpbb js is based on classes to toggle dropdowns for example but in bootstrap there are the same classes.

Answer (score 3):

No. In a webpage, the script environment is the whole page.

You can, mostly, avoid global conflicts by using IIFE to limit scope.

```
(function () {
    var local_variable;
    function local_function() { }
})();
```

You can load a separate page in an `iframe` to keep it completely independent (baring code which intentionally accesses `top` or `parent`).

Comment: Thx for the answer but can you explain me more precisely how to use (place) this function pls ? I don't know that function. For the iframe, I don't want this because I want a fully integration of my forum and a iframe will return always the same url.

Comment: "can you explain me more precisely how to use (place) this function" — Not really. There isn't really anything else to say.

Comment: In fact I don't really understand what you mean. Shall I encapsulated all my forum functions in a function ?

Comment: I don't know. Localising the scope of variables is good general strategy for minimising conflicts with other scripts.  Whether or not that will solve your problem depends on what the actual problem is.